# I can't use R CMD BUILD because I have no build file in R\R-3.4.0\bin

Tags: r, cmd, build, package

I have not build file in the binary of my version of R. Should I try to get it to be able to use R CMD BUILD (how?) or should I try to build a package in another way?

Answer (score 2):

While `INSTALL` is capitalized (to avoid clashes with the existing `/usr/bin/install`, as are a few others as shown below), the `build` command is not:

```
edd@rob:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/R/bin/
total 488
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1837 Jul  2 19:39 BATCH
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    350 Jul  2 19:39 build
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    317 Jul  2 19:39 check
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2165 Jul  2 19:39 COMPILE
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11377 Jul  2 19:39 config
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul 15 20:25 exec
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3618 Jul  2 19:39 f77_f2c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    823 Jul  2 19:39 INSTALL
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14530 Jul  2 19:39 javareconf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 355913 Jul  2 19:39 libtool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1442 Jul  2 19:39 LINK
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3496 Jul  2 19:39 mkinstalldirs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    483 Jul  2 19:39 pager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   8722 Jul  2 19:39 R
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1375 Jul  2 19:39 Rcmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    316 Jul  2 19:39 Rd2pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    359 Jul  2 19:39 Rdconv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    258 Jul  2 19:39 Rdiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    158 Jul  2 19:39 REMOVE
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    310 Jul  2 19:39 Rprof
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14344 Jul  2 19:39 Rscript
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4121 Jul  2 19:39 rtags
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    155 Jul  2 19:39 SHLIB
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    318 Jul  2 19:39 Stangle
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    316 Jul  2 19:39 Sweave
edd@rob:~$
```

So make sure you type `R CMD build ...` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk. It works now, which is the most important although it is mysterious to me since I have not found any "build" file related to R in my whole computer. Maybe these things are now done in an exe file. Any opinion welcome about this

'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin>ls
R.exe  Rscript.exe  config.sh  i386  x64'

'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\x64>ls
R.dll  RSetReg.exe  Rcmd.exe  Rgraphapp.dll  Riconv.dll   Rscript.exe  open.exe
R.exe  Rblas.dll    Rfe.exe   Rgui.exe       Rlapack.dll  Rterm.exe'